# Spliting pharagraphs from a text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, split

Helo, I have a code that supose to take a text from a textarea and make an Array that contains all pharagraphs in this text.

like turn this:

```
Hello, thats the first pharagraph
Hello, thats the second pharagraph
```

into this:

```
["Hello, thats the first pharagraph", "Hello, thats the second pharagraph"]
```

I tried to make the split using the "/n" on argument of split function,like this:

```
//take the text from textarea
var texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
//split text into array
texto = texto.split("/n");
```

But all I got was an array like this:

```
["Hello, thats the first pharagraph↵Hello, thats the second pharagraph"]
```

I tried to put the "enter" character on split, but didnt work too
Note that this have to work with "copy and paste" text and "input" text

I have no idea how to make this work, thanks if you can help me

Comment: You want `\n`, not `/n`.

Answer (score 0):

The new line should be `\n`.

See snippet below:

```js
function getTextArea() {
  const texto = document.querySelector('#texto').value;
  console.log(texto.split('\n'));
}
```

```html
<textarea id="texto" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
<button onclick="getTextArea()">Get Text</button>
```